# php/mysql client management software?

Tags: php, crm, ticket-system

I'm looking for some software that will allow me to do the following:

[alt text http://patrickg.net/lookingfor.png](http://patrickg.net/lookingfor.png)

I don't need anything fancy, just basic information, back and forth dated comments, etc. No payment integration, or file handling.

Thought I'd ask before I write my own

Comment: Something of a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/98018/which-php-open-source-crm-should-i-use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good luck with that - but from what I've seen, most of the stuff out there have x100 more features, and an appropriate learning curve. I don't know if you can find something with the *exact* features you've asked.

What's the problem with rolling your own, though? As long as you use a framework, isn't it just a couple days' work (maybe even a day)? Learning/using a full-fledged CMS might take more time.

Comment: i agree that it's probably easier to make your own if you just want a few simple things. I'm actually planning on doing something like this for myself, but with some sort of bug tracking and file uploads.

Answer (score 1):

This may be overkill, but you may want to take a look at [SugarCRM](http://www.sugarcrm.com)

Comment: ive used sugarcrm before, wow is that thing huge!

Comment: I am using sugarCRM at work and indeed it is biiiiiigggggggggg :D